# Javascript - Resumir este tipo de scripts

Tags: javascript

Hay alguna forma de **resumir o reescribir** éste script...?

Ahora el siguiente ejemplo es muy fácil, **porque son sólo 3 divs** los que hay a abrir y cerrar, pero el problema es que cada vez se hace más y más grande (puede llegar a 250-300 divs), y por lo visto aquí comparten algunas funciones, como al hacer click en **.layer-2** se cierra el div abierto en éste momento.

Alguna idea...?

**CSS**

```
.layer-2 {display:none}    
#info-1 {display:none}
#youtube-1 {display:none}
#ver-carrito {display:none}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#uno").click(function(){
    $("#info-1,.layer-2").show();
  });
    $(".cerrar,.layer-2").click(function(){
      $("#info-1,.layer-2").hide();
  });
});

//-----------------

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dos").click(function(){
    $("#youtube-1,.layer-2").show();
  });
    $(".layer-2").click(function(){
      $("#youtube-1,.layer-2").hide();
  });
});

//-----------------

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".carrito").click(function(){
    $("#ver-carrito,.layer-2").show();
  });
    $("#close-ver-carrito,.layer-2").click(function(){
      $("#ver-carrito,.layer-2").hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola Pablo como estas?,

Se me ocurre que si se repiten funcionalidades en mismos objetos, lo que podes hacer es agruparlos. Por ejemplo coloco en un array todos los elementos y despues los recorro para agregarles el evento click que es igual para todos ellos.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      [
        $(".carrito"),
        $(".carrito2"),
        $(".carrito3"),
        $(".carrito4"),
      ].map((item)=>{
        item.click(function(){
           $("#ver-carrito,.layer-2").show();
        });
    });
```

Y asi para cualquier evento que quieras repetir para varios divs.

Espero que sea de ayuda. Suerte!

Comment: Gracias **Facundo Fernanez**, Lo tendré en cuenta. Un saludo